# InStr Function - input a search parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following str function in a macro to look for a string and delete the entire row,  if a match is found.

```
If InStr(.Value, "@@@") = 0 Then .EntireRow.Delete
```

My question is as follows : Is it possible to enter a search pattern from a cell location, for example instead of hard coding `"@@@"` as the search term in the macro i would like the search term to come from `Sheet1` , cell `A1`.
I have tried using a text string as follows, but it deleted all the contents

```
Dim term As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
term = Range("A1").Value
If InStr(.Value, "term") = 0 Then .EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: `InStr(.Value, "term")` you are looking for the string`"term"`, not the value of the variable `term`. remove the quotes.

Comment: You have not posted a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't know what `.Value` you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks Vincent - The macro i have is a lengthy macro so i thought just the inStr function would be enough to supply. Having said that,  your solution to my problem is the correct one i.e use term , NOT "term"

Answer (score 0):

Just use `term = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value`

`Sheets` collection contains also charts, etc. so it's better to use `worksheets` IMO.

Also, don't use `Select` as it is bad practice ([Avoid using SELECT or ACTIVATE](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate))

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        If InStr(1, .Range("A1").Value, "@@@") = 0 Then
            .Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

**Note:** If you re planning to loop and if the condition meet delete the row, you must loop from bottom to top.